# 72 Horsepower DC Motor

Tags: dc-motor, specifications

The previous owner of my sailboat installed an electric DC motor and batteries. I cannot find any specifications on this motor besides what is on the plate on the motor housing.

The plate says:

Advanced DC Motors Inc.

- Part No. AC4-4002
- Volts DC- 72
- Serial No. 138
- Rating 2.940
- 57B loT

I would like to know horsepower, rpm range, and anything else about the motor. I have searched the internet for hours and once in a while find the motor part number but no other information is provided.

Comment: 72 volts does not remotely imply 72 Horsepower.  Realistically speaking,what do do you hope to learn?  Does it move the boat usefully or not?

Comment: Measure the length and diameter of the motor. Now google for the same type of motor, with similar volume. The power should be broadly similar.

Answer (score 1):

I am saying that your yacht does not have a 72 HP DC motor. Yachts, unlike, say, jetboats and outboards, have what's called a displacement hull. This means that it's good in choppy water and it needs very little power to go slowly. In fact, more power won't help speed much. If you look at the wiring and ballpark the current at your known voltage of 72 V then the kW will be apparent. You can ballpark the efficiency of the DC motor at, say, 90%. Remember that 1 HP is 735 watts (horsepower according to DIN 66036) and then you are done. I would also study the size and hence kWh of the heavy onboard battery pack and use this to support a much lower answer.

Comment: One HP equals to 746 watts... Not 735.

Comment: @soosaisteven A metric horsepower is 735 watts.

Comment: Horsepower has always being imperial.... No such thing as metric horsepower.

Comment: @soosaisteven See DIN 66036.

Comment: "kWh " for kilowatt-hours. KWH = kelvin watt henries = nonsense.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha.... Once I was told mmHg is millimeter Henry grams...

Comment: Andrew Morton, thanks for the enlightenment. I didn't know about this before.

Comment: As an example; I have an 8.0 meter sailboat that uses 6HP to reach full hull speed. Although it is equipped with a 36HP engine. Only the water line length determines top hull speed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only approximation i was able to find:

http://edriver.me/ev3.html

Advanced DC AC4-4002 6.7" 72 volt

- 10"x 6.7"
- Series wound
- 47 Lbs
- 20 HP (Nom 6.5, peak 27)
- should be kept below 5700-5800 RPM

Other "findings", for you to check the motor driver details if you require -between 300 and 400A on these pages. One of these projects even uses batteries too...

http://www.bcsportbikes.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-60269.html

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Used-Advanced-72V-DC-Motor-ADC-AC4-4002-EV-Electric-Vehicle-Car-Go-Kart-NR-/321092042836/?_ul=BO

http://www.formula-hybrid.org/pdf/program-2008.pdf (page 6, right paragraph)

Enjoy!...